# what is fundamental group of projective plane with 2 points identified?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have a problem with finding the fundamental group of projective plane with 2 points identified.I try to solve this question using van Kampen theorem .
Lets $p$ and $q$ be the identified points and considered projective plane as $\Bbb RP^2$ . I consider $U$ as the open neighborhood of $\Bbb RP^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ and $V$ the open neighborhood of the identified points.
I don't know whether this work or not.

Comment: In order to apply van Kampen's theorem, you need to make sure that $U\cap V$ is path-connected. It is not clear from your description why this is guaranteed, so I think you need more details on how to choose such open neighborhood. A diagram might be helpful.